# problems with augment and ggplot on list in R

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, spline, broom

my data set is:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  x1= as.factor(1:3), 
  x2= as.factor (4:6), 
  x3= as.factor(7:9), 
  x4= as.factor (2:7), 
  x5= as.factor(1:6), 
  x6= as.numeric(1:18),
  x7= as.numeric(18:35)
  )
```

I want to do a spline on x6 and x7, but before I group x1,x2, x3, x4, x5, i do:

```
mydata1 <- mydata%>%
    nest(-(x1:x5))%>%
    mutate(fit = map(data, ~spline(.$x6,.$x7)))
```

now I want to use broom::augment, but spline is a list. another problem is that I want to do a plot (with ggplot2):

```
ggplot(data= mydata%>%, aes(x = x6, y = x7))+
    geom_line(aes(color = x1, linetype = x2))+
    geom_line(data= mydata1$fit, aes(x= .$x, y= .$y,color = x1,linetype = x2))+
    facet_grid(x3~x4, scales = "free")
```

but give me an error:"Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list", beacuse ggplot wants a dataframe and not list. is there a method to have fit as dataframe or to use augment on list?
if I can use augment, I can do this:

```
mydata1 <- mydata%>%
    nest(-(x1:x5))%>%
    mutate(fit = map(data, ~spline(.$x6,.$x7)),
           result = map(fit, augment))%>%
    unnest(result)
```

and so I have .fitted in a dataframe and I can use ggplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

data_frame(
  x1=as.factor(1:3), 
  x2=as.factor (4:6), 
  x3=as.factor(7:9), 
  x4=as.factor (2:7), 
  x5=as.factor(1:6), 
  x6=as.numeric(1:18),
  x7=as.numeric(18:35)
) -> mydata

mydata %>%
  nest(-(x1:x5))%>%
  mutate(fit=map(data, ~as_data_frame(spline(.$x6, .$x7)))) -> mydata1
```

At this point, `mydata$fit` is a column of data frames with `x` and `y` columns.

You can do this for the plotting:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=mydata, 
            aes(x=x6, y=x7, color=x1, linetype=x2))+
  geom_line(data=select(mydata1, -data) %>% unnest(fit), 
            aes(x=x, y=y, color=x1, linetype=x2)) +
  facet_grid(x3~x4, scales="free")
```